# Separating anomalys using Isolation Forest, Is my approach correct?

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I am a fairly new guy to ML and I am having some trouble choosing a algorithm to the job for me. My data set consists physical measurements where part of the samples were contaminated. In this case, the contamination means that I am not 100% percent sure if I am actually measuring the material I want to measure or the contaminant. Besides that, I have the physical characterization of the contaminant, so I know how it behaves.

So, by now, I did this: I trained an Isolation forest algorithm with the measurements of the contaminant and then classified the actual data using the trained forest. The result seems reasonable, but does this approach make sense?

I am little confused since, at least for a new guy like me, this seemed like a non-orthodox way of use the algorithm. Besides, since my actual dataset does not have labels I can't test the goodness of the classification. Thank you!

Comment: It it a binary whether you are measuring sample or contaminant? Or can it be a mix?

Comment: Have you tried clustering your data? Possibly your two cases would show up there

Comment: But sure, your setup is a 'One class classification'. In anomaly detection the usual approach is to model the normal data, not the outliers. But that is mostly because one wants to be conservative regarding new/unknown outliers - want these to be also considered anomalies. If this is not the case for you, either you know that there can only ever be one contaminant or you don't care about others - then your approach makes sense

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, people! I can have some mixing of contaminant and measuring (e.g, a sample might be a mixture of the contaminant physical behavior and the normal data), so there is some kind of transition between the samples that are clear contamination and the ones that are clear not anomaly. So the main goal would be to generate a decision boundary to classify the samples on this transition. The relationship of the variables measured are somewhat complex, so the more common clustering algorithms did not performed well.